# Given is a uniformly distributed random variable $u \in (0,1)$ and density. How can you create a random variable with that density?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Assume you have an uniformly distributed random variable $u \in (0,1).$
>   How can you create a random variable with density
>
> $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\text{ if
> }x\geq 0\\  \frac{1}{2}e^x \;\;\;\;\text{ else} \end{matrix}\right.
> \;\;\;\;$ ?

We first need to know the (cumulative) distribution function of the density function, so we can continue by inverting that distribution function.

The distribution function is $$F(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12e^x & \mbox{if }x < 0 \\
\frac12+\frac1\pi \arctan (x) & \mbox{if } x \ge0
\end{cases}$$

(which is correct because my previous question was about it: [Determine the distribution function of this density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623856/determine-the-distribution-function-of-this-density-function/2623875#2623875)).

We are looking for its inverse now (I'm not sure if it's correct like that):

$$i = \frac{1}{2}e^x \Leftrightarrow 2i = e^x \Leftrightarrow x = \ln(2i)$$

$$i=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi} \arctan(x) \Leftrightarrow i-\frac{1}{2}= \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(x) \Leftrightarrow \pi\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\arctan(x) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow x = \tan\left(\pi\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Thus the inverse of the distribution function is 
$$F^{-1}(i)=\begin{cases}
\ln(2i) & \mbox{if }i > 0 \\
\tan\left(\pi\left(i-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) & \mbox{if } i \le0
\end{cases}$$

Assuming this is correct, how would you get the random variable by this? Is it the maximum possible $i$?

Comment: what does it mean create? what does the uniform have to to with X?

Comment: @HardCore Actually I wasn't sure how to phrase it :p Maybe I should have rather written "simulate a random variable by the given density" or something like that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that if $F(x) = y$ then $y \in [0,1]$. Also, in your case, $F(0) = 1/2$. Therefore,
$$F^{-1}(y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\ln(2y) & \text{if $0 \le y \le \frac{1}{2}$;}\\ \tan\left(\pi\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le y \le 1$.}\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now, set $X = F^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ is a uniform random variable that takes on values between $0$ and $1$. It is easy to observe that $$F_X(x) = \Pr(X \le x) = \Pr(F^{-1}(U) \le x) = \Pr(U \le F(x)) = F(x).$$
Here, I have used the fact that $F_U(u) = \Pr(U \le u)= u$ for $u \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

The domain of the inverse is $(0,1)$. The switch between the two pieces of the original CDF is at the $y$ value of $1/2$, so that will be where the switch in the inverse happens. Other than that, your inverse is correct. The point of this is then that if $U$ is $\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ distributed then $F^{-1}(U)$ has the distribution of the variable you want. This trick is called the probability integral transformation; it is one of the main ways that random variables are sampled in numerical computation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a practical answer it is very simple.
The theoretical framework you want to look at is called **inverse transform method**, you can google it.

Once you have obtained the inverse CDF as you did you would use a software to generate random numbers from a uniform between 0 and 1.

The outcome of the simulation is your $i$.

You would therefore feed the outcome of the simulation to the $F^{-1}(i)$ and you are done.

$F^{-1}(i)$ is your random number simulated from the CDF $F$ (basically is your $x$).